# How to pass data from angular to node js server?

Tags: node.js, angular

My app.component.ts contains

```
login() {
    var user = `{ email: ${this.email}, password: ${this.password} }`
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
                    .set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
                    .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/signin', user, {
          headers: headers 
    }).subscribe(data => {

   });
   console.log(`email: ${this.email} password: ${this.password}`) 
}
```

When trying to get the data  in node I get

> error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 2

I am using

> req.body

to get the data. 
What is the correct way to parse the JSON data? Also wanted to know if this is the correct way to pass form data from angular to node?

Comment: You should stringify the `user`  like this : `JSON.stringify(user)`

Comment: That gives  error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

Comment: have you print `user` in console.log what you get there

Comment: Yes. I get it correct.

Comment: @TechTeam You use Angular 6 HttpClient ?

Comment: @AdrienSAULNIER Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var user = { 
    email: this.email, 
    password: this.password 
}
...
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/signin',user).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: why should i remove the headers ?

Comment: You should change the "user" to be Object type rather than String type

Answer (score 1):

```
user= {
   email: aka@gmail.com,
   password: 123,
    }               
            $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: http://localhost:3000/signin,
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                headers: headers 
            }).success(function(data) {
               // you can print data hera
                }
            }).error(function() {

            });
```

Comment: this has to be added in app.component.html file ?

Comment: you can also use the RXJS library , to hit the API, using RXJS library is the better way

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 6 HttpClient, you don't need to stringify your object ([see POST example from official doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)). In the same way, for a GET request, HttpClient parse json data for you.

Try this :

```
login() {
   const user = { email: this.email, password: this.password };

   const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   });

   this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/signin', user, {
     headers: headers 
   }).subscribe(data => {});
 console.log(`email: ${this.email} password: ${this.password}`) }
```

Answer (score 0):

First i thought you using an object for the user, than a saw it's a string.
Your data is not with correct json format.
Try to put quotes on the fields name

```
var user = `{ "email": ${this.email}, "password": ${this.password} }`
```

WRONG!

> You should stringify the data -  **JSON.stringify(user)**
>
> ```
> this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/signin', JSON.stringify(user), {
>   headers: headers 
> }).subscribe(data => {
>
> });
> ```

Comment: that gives error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

Comment: also doing this makes it to a string whereas i have mentioned in the header to use content type json

Comment: Yeah, I saw I was wrong, I edit my answer. This should work.

Comment: Okay. But i still get error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0. I should be fetching it using request.body , right ?